# How many documents were removed in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Using Spring Data (1.1.0.M1) is there a way to determine how many documents were removed?

Currently I'm using the [`remove()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.1.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) method on the `MongoTemplate` class, but it does not return any sort of information about the operation.

If not through `MongoTemplate`, is there a different way to remove documents and also find out how many were removed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write documents in MongoDB (including removing) you can call [getLastError()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command) to see what effect your last write operation had.

The problem you have is that when there is no error, you still want to know how many objects (documents) were affected by your operation.

In the shell you can see the details by examining the object returned by `getLastErrorObj()`.   In Java the Mongo Java driver provides [methods](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html#getN%28%29) to do the equivalent.

In the case of a remove operation, the field `"n"` will correspond to the number of affected documents.  Here's a small snippet of an example:

```
import com.mongodb.WriteResult;
...
   WriteResult wr = collection.remove(new BasicDBObject());  // removes everything
   System.out.println(wr.getN());        // prints the number of removed documents
```

Answer (score 0):

I Don't have much experience with MongoDB as I'm new to it, not sure if what I'm about to reccomend applies to your situation. When passing the flag safe=true to a query it returns a key 'n' that shows the amount of affected rows in the query. You should look into it..